# web app make db on first run of python code

Tags: python, sqlite, path, aiohttp

I have an aiohttp app where when ran the first time it will attempt to create an sqlite db if it doesnt exist on a `try_make_db()` function. I also don't think an exception error is a good way to do this either...

Could someone give me a tip on how to make this better?

When run the file I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 280, in <module>
    try_make_db()
  File "app.py", line 250, in try_make_db
    with sqlite3.connect(my_path) as conn:
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I dont think this has anything to do with aiohttp or sqlite but more of a PATH question.

This isn't the entire code but only near the bottom, here's a [gist of the entire script](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/555560e86b1846a17a6e186f1f68f91d#file-aioapp-py):

```
def try_make_db() -> None:
    my_path = './form_data.db'
    with sqlite3.connect(my_path) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print("Trying to connect to the db!")
        try:
            cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM posts LIMIT 1;")
            cur.close()
            print("Good enough DB should be Ok")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Table 'posts' does not exist")
            cur.execute(
                """CREATE TABLE posts (
                Date TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                starttime TEXT,
                endtime TEXT,
                Weekends NUMBER,
                Weekdays NUMBER,
                setpoint NUMBER)
            """
            )
            print("DB TABLE CREATED")
            conn.commit()

async def init_db(app: web.Application) -> AsyncIterator[None]:
    sqlite_db = 'form_data.db'
    db = await aiosqlite.connect(sqlite_db)
    db.row_factory = aiosqlite.Row
    app["DB"] = db
    yield
    await db.close()

try_make_db()


web.run_app(init_app()  , host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Any tips greatly appreciated not a lot of wisdom here. Would anyone have a tip on how I could modify the `try_to_make_db` function maybe something like this:

```
import os.path
if os.path.exists(PATH_TO_DB): # replace the path here
  print("Path exists")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check write permissions on form_data.db also you don't need to use ./ to explicitly state your current working directory, just using the name form_data.db will create the file in same dir as your main program.